# Stop return of Tesseract js recognize property

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, return, tesseract

I'm using Teseractjs to turn images to text but there is a problem with the recognize function of teseract.

```
$.when( cal1(), cal2() ).done( function(){
        alert("Complete");
    });

    function cal1(){
    Tesseract.recognize(imagen_elegida1,{
    }).then( function(a){ 
        text1 = a.text;
     });
    }
    function cal2(){
    Tesseract.recognize(imagen_elegida2,{
    }).then( function(b){ 
        text2 = b.text;
     } );
    }
```

I want to send the alert after

> text1=a.text and text2=b.text

but it sent it when recognize property is done.

There is a way to stop the return of Tesseract.recognize and the assign return to

> .then()

???

This is the page of the lib http://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/ . I couldn't find too much information. I was trying things like return none or void function cal1() to stop the return but nothing seems to work.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I understood your question is you want to print your extracted text after Tesseract recognizes the text.

Tesseract.recognize function accepts a third argument for success. The callback will be called after Tesseract recognizes the Text.

```
Tesseract.recognize(image, options, callback); 
function callback (error, result) {
    alert(result.text) // This is the final output text of Tesseract. 
}
```

PS: Tesseract requires you to specify the language of the text being extracted I think.

Thanks!

Comment: That Works for just 1 Image, what i want to do is process a lot of images and after all is correctly done send an alert. It is posible?